# ggplot2: faceting on a function of column

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Couldn't find an answer to this -- in ggplot2, is it possible to facet on a *function* of a column, rather than on the value of the column directly?

Simple reproducible example:

Sample data:

```
df=data.frame(dat=c(1,2,5,5,7))
```

This works:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:5, y=dat, colour=factor(dat > 3))) + 
       geom_point() + facet_grid(dat ~ .)
```

This does not:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:5, y=dat, colour=factor(dat > 3))) + 
       geom_point() + facet_grid((dat > 3) ~ .)
```

One solution is to add a column just for the facet. This works:

```
df$facet=df$dat>3
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:5, y=dat, colour=factor(dat > 3))) + 
       geom_point() + facet_grid(facet ~ .)
```

But is there a way to do it without having to add a new column to the data.frame?

Comment: What is the problem with adding a new column? I would rather expect that adding a new column is faster because of taking advantage of native R functions and vectorization.

Comment: My primary aversion to adding a new column is just that it seems inelegant. ggplot2 can handle coloring by a function of a factor -- what about faceting? What if you want to do do this on several different functions of a factor but not clutter your dataframe with extra columns, or bother with creating and deleting them?

Comment: I get your point - I have been there, too - but at the end of the day it is just a cosmetical issue and if you ask me, as much as I enjoy R, it is an inelegant language by design - its purpose is to get the job done well, but not elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a compromise solution, which is a trade-off between arguments of @Nathan and @Яaffael posted in the comment section.

```
FacetingFunction <- function(df) {df$dat > 3}
ArbitraryFacetingPlot <- function(df, FacetingFunction) {
  df$facet <- FacetingFunction(df)
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=1:5, y=dat, colour=factor(dat > 3))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(facet ~ .)
  df$facet <- NULL
  p
}

ArbitraryFacetingPlot(df, FacetingFunction)
ArbitraryFacetingPlot(df, function(df) {df$dat==5})
```